# extract multiple list embeded in a string in python

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a string like following:

```
"sring = [[61252,'1','1','30000','2617','2677','15000','1'],[61252,'2','2','72590','2615','2678','15000','1'],[61252,'3','1','9354','2608','2690','709','1']]"
```

I want to convert it to a regular list like :

```
list = [[61252,'1','1','30000','2617','2677','15000','1'],[61252,'2','2','72590','2615','2678','15000','1'],[61252,'3','1','9354','2608','2690','709','1']]
```

and then I can parse it or do whatever can done with lists.
I tried to split the string but it doesn't work becuase the result was a string.

I even try to convert it using `exec` function:

```
exec('func = lambda : {}; func()').string
```

but it doesn't return anything.
Is there any (clean) way to convert this kind of string to appropriate list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) after splitting the string around the `=`. Please pay close attention to the extra space trailing the `=`, as it is necessary to ensure that the `literal_eval` can properly *process* the string structure passed. Otherwise you will be faced with an exception of `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Solution:

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = "sring = [[61252,'1','1','30000','2617','2677','15000','1'],[61252,'2','2','72590','2615','2678','15000','1'],[61252,'3','1','9354','2608','2690','709','1']]"

res = literal_eval(s.split('= ')[1])
print(res)
print(type(res))
```

Output:

```
[[61252, '1', '1', '30000', '2617', '2677', '15000', '1'], [61252, '2', '2', '72590', '2615', '2678', '15000', '1'], [61252, '3', '1', '9354', '2608', '2690', '709', '1']]
<class 'list'>
```

Extra Note: I noticed you assigned your list in your example to a variable named *list*. Please be aware that *list* is a builtin name in Python and using that as a variable name will shadow the built-in and could lead to problems in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your (fast and good) answer and your note, I know `list` is a built-in name in python I just wanted to declare that the first one is a string and the second one has a list type.
and one more thing can you explain breifly what is ast and what is literal_eval?

Comment: @Mehdi You're welcome. Per the documentation, the `ast` module, standing for *abstract syntax tree*, which you can read about [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) is pretty well explained in the documentation. Ultimately, an AST is a general computer science concept, which you can also read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). For `literal_eval`, I have a link in the answer that explains exactly how it works. Here it is again: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 1):

well in your case you can just slice string like list! cause ultimately it is list of characters.

```
x="sring = [[61252,'1','1','30000','2617','2677','15000','1'],[61252,'2','2','72590','2615','2678','15000','1'],[61252,'3','1','9354','2608','2690','709','1']]"

x=x[x.index('['):x[::-1].index(']')*-1])) # if any trailing chars in staring
```

> **in your case you can just use** x=x[x.index('['):]
>
> This will slice your string and then you can just use list_x = eval(x) to get actual list

Answer (score -2):

Just `exec` the string

```
exec("sring = [[61252,'1','1','30000','2617','2677','15000','1'],[61252,'2','2','72590','2615','2678','15000','1'],[61252,'3','1','9354','2608','2690','709','1']]")
```